# Execute IHttpHandler to MemoryStream

Tags: c#, httphandler, ihttphandler, httpserverutility

I am wanting to use something like [`HttpServerUtility.Execute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150027.aspx) to execute an [`IHttpHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) and write the handler response to a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) that can then be parsed into an http response (functionally, I want access to the headers and the content returned).

Currently the [`HttpServerUtility.Execute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150027.aspx) method has a parameter for a [`TextWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.aspx) object (can be a [`StringWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter.aspx) object) but this only caters for requests that return a text/string body, also I cannot read the content-type header of the response (say for a text/css response). If say I had a handler that I wanted to execute that outputs an image the [`StringWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter.aspx) would not work as this deals with binary data.

Basically I want to execute one [`IHttpHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) (could be a [`System.Web.UI.Page`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx)) inside another [`IHttpHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) and store the response in a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx).

Any assistance with this would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you won't get everything in the provided TextWriter? The HttpResponse class tests if it's outputting to the standard HttpWriter or not and reacts accordingly (bytes should be written using the Default encoding). Have you tested it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can invoke the ProcessRequest method on the IHttpHandler object directly and pass it your own http context with your own response object. I'm not sure but I think the BinaryWrite method of the http response uses the output stream of the TextWriter object that is passed into it's constructor. So if you have a memory stream set in the TextWriter then you could use it as your output.

So:

- Create MemoryStream
- Create StreamWriter and pass memory stream into the constructor
- Create a HttpResponse and pass it the created StreamWriter
- Create an HttpContext with the created HttpResponse and a created or current http request
- Invoke IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

Comment: This is likely what I would try first - with a minor modification: Create a `HttpWorkerRequest`-derived class to encapsulate your memory stream, trap the header/body writes in the overrides for that class to route to the `MemoryStream`, then extract the buffer when done - then you create a new `HttpContext(HttpWorkerRequest wr)` and pass that to `ProcessRequest`.